# How to debug an app on another handset without having access to that handset

Tags: android, debugging

I'm making an app for Android in Eclipse. Currently the app works fine on my Droid Incredible, but it does not work at all on my friends' model which I emailed the apk to. Is there a way for me to emulate different phone models to run the app on without physically having them?

Thanks

Comment: Not easily. You can create an emulator with 'physical' characteristics such as screen resolution, SD card etc. but you also have to install all the same apps which wouldn't be possible for the manufacturer's proprietary apps. The best thing to do would be to put extensive logging in place and get your friend to use one of the 'logcat' apps available on the Market to email you the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. The long answer is that emulators are never perfect as they don't simulate the electronics of the devices but the logic in them. You should run automated tests on your device and if possible in physical target devices. There's a service, similar to vnc, i didn't used this service nor do i recommend it, but it exists, it's called deviceanywhere , google it, it offers remote testing on real hardware, but of course it's a paid service.
Another way to test the application is to give a beta version to android forums and get feedback from users, and don't forget to include internal tests and logging.